# AJAX Post Showing loader and message won't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

This is my problem, Ajax is working great, processing all data but for some reason, which I ignore at the moment, it's not displaying the loader and the success div.

My **html** is something like

```
<form id="msform" action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <!-- some fields -->
    <input type="submit" Value="submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="processing" class="row" style="display:none"></div>

<div id="apf-response" class="row" style="display:none"></div>
```

My jQuery / AJAX is lookin like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#msform').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    apfaddpost();
  })
})

function apfaddpost() {
  var fd = new FormData($('#msform')[0]);
  fd.append( "main_image", $('#main_image')[0].files[0]);
  fd.append( "action", 'apf_addpost');      

  //Append here your necessary data
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: apfajax.ajaxurl,
    data: fd, 
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function(){ 
      //here should be the issue. I'm hiding the form and showing the loader div
      $('#msform').hide();
      $('#processing').show();
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
      //when it's completed hide loader and show success message
      $('#processing').hide();
      $('#apf-response').show();
      var id = '#success';
      jQuery(id).html('');
      jQuery(id).append(data);
      resetvalues($('#msform'));
    },
    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

Is this the correct way? What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Is that possible that this issue could be given by `event.preventDefault();` or `action="#"`?

**Solved**

I've changed my jQuery code into

```
function apfaddpost() {
    var fd = new FormData($('#msform')[0]);
    fd.append( "main_image", $('#main_image')[0].files[0]);
    fd.append( "action", 'apf_addpost');   

    $('#form-container').hide();
    $('#processing').show();
    var postProject = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: apfajax.ajaxurl,
        data: fd, 
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
    });

    postProject.done(function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            $('#processing').hide();
            $('#apf-response').show();
            var id = '#success';
            jQuery(id).html('');
            jQuery(id).append(data);
            resetvalues($('#msform'));
    });

    postProject.fail(function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
    });
}
```

It worked!

Comment: try to put  $("#processing").show(); before ajax request start.

Comment: @DharaParmar Unfortunately it doesn't work putting that before

Comment: Are you able to confirm that the success handler is being fired when the AJAX call is made? Also, it is actually easier if you use promises, like `.done()` and `.fail()`, chained to your AJAX object instead of using nested `success` or `error` handlers.

Comment: @Terry Yes Ajax handler is successfully fired. If I change display:none in my console, I see the message. I've tried to change it with `.done()` and `.fail`. Always successful but still not showing loader and message.

Comment: @Terry Actually thanks for your suggestion! I did some mistake using `.done()` and `.fail()`. Now it's working! Great.

Comment: Good ti know that it worked :)

Answer (score -1):

If you add the `loader` in form tag it will work properly

```
<form id="msform">
  <fieldset>
    <!-- some fields -->
    <input type="submit" Value="submit">
  </fieldset>

  <div id="processing" class="row" style="display:none"></div>
  <div id="apf-response" class="row" style="display:none"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: It doesn't work because I hide the whole form as you can see by my code.